# MVC - How to turn the row selected into a variable to use in functions throughout the code?

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I have a SQL Server database within an ASP.NET Core MVC app.

(1) The SQL database contains a table with the following columns: SEQ (int), NAME (varchar(50)), LAST NAME (varchar(50)), AGE (int) and HEIGHT (float).

(2) The MVC app contains a summary table that contains two columns: The Sequence (seq) and Name information that comes from the SQL table(1).

(3) I would like to select a row from the table (2) and use the var name (string) to use in functions throughout the code, for example,  execute a select to retrieve the rest of the information in the database and add it to other fields in the view...

Here is the cshtml code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <table id="table-resumida" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Seq.</th>
                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr style="cursor: pointer" onclick="?">
                    <td>
                        @item.SEQ
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.NAME
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I think you could use the row's primary key as an id in the html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.